# Is there a recommended sound quality for a shofar?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

I have a preference for blowing a shofar that produces a clear low pitched sound. (Of course, when I choose a shofar, my higher priority is that it's lightweight and is easy for me to blow.)

[O.C. 586:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=119&hilite=) (Thanks DoubleAA for providing ref) says that "all types of voices" are considered kosher, meaning that if the sounds is dull or "heavy", they are valid.

I'm curious if outside of halacha, are there any other sources stating any recommendations regarding the preferred or "ideal" sound quality of the shofar, and what the reasons would be.

Comment: Personally, I prefer shofrot with darker, more mellow timbres in the baritone-tenor ranges, but that's not sourced in halacha.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Yup. That sounds like a good description of my preference. Yesterday morning, I heard a shofar with a loud nasally voice that I thought I was standing next to the sheep, themselves!

Comment: The Rambam clearly states that the different classes of sounds we make with the shofar represent different kinds of crying - sobbing, wailing, and sighing (truah, t'kia, shevarim).  So the tone should probably be in the higher register.

Comment: @YaakovEphraim Ramba"m and others essentially describe the tempo. If you are able to find a source that discusses the pitch or timbre, please post that as an answer.